# xcode counting JSON items

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

I need to Count the number of Items (post) in this JSON response,

```
2012-06-04 14:09:57.872 horitable[72261:11903] JSON : {
posts =     (
            {
        post =             {
            eventdate = "2012-03-31";
            eventid = 2;
            eventimage = "http://hernandoz.local/~hernandoz/kopict/02_31march2012.jpg";
            eventinfo = "02 event";
            eventname = "xplosion 02";
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            eventdate = "2012-07-07";
            eventid = 3;
            eventimage = "http://hernandoz.local/~hernandoz/kopict/greg_vs_turner.jpg";
            eventinfo = "02 event";
            eventname = "Xplosion 02";
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            eventdate = "2012-04-29";
            eventid = 4;
            eventimage = "http://hernandoz.local/~hernandoz/kopict/ko_itclub_apr_2012.jpg";
            eventinfo = "KO East London Interclub";
            eventname = "KO Interclub";
        };
    }
);
```

}

I know there are only 3 events (post), this is the code I am using

```
 [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
    NSLog(@"JSON : %@", JSON); //get the JSON response

    // 6.1 - Load JSON into internal variable
    jsonResponse = JSON;
    // 6.2 - Get the number of shows (post)
    int shows = 0;
    for (NSDictionary* day in jsonResponse) {
        shows += [[day objectForKey:@"posts"] count];

        NSLog(@"count : %d",shows);
    }
```

I  get an error , but I don't understand why .

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76986f0
```

can someone please help me out . Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that u have properly allocated the NSDictionary

Comment: jsonResponse is NSArray and JSON is ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was JSON as an ID, this works

`jsonResponse = [(NSDictionary*)JSON objectForKey:@"posts"];`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSLog(@"Response members= %@",responseString);
NSArray *array = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"posts"];
NSLog(@"Count value= %d",[array count]);
```

Comment: Hi I what is that JSONValue ? i am not using any external libraries, only AFNetworking..thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can do this

```
 [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
 NSLog(@"JSON : %@", JSON); //get the JSON response

// 6.1 - Load JSON into internal variable
jsonResponse = JSON;
// 6.2 - Get the number of shows (post)
int shows = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"posts"] count];

   NSLog(@"count : %d",shows);
```

Comment: I get an error -  No visible @interface for NSarray declares the selector 'objectforkey'

Comment: objectForKey not objectforkey

Comment: yea it was the way I typed the error but it is objectForKey in Xcode

Comment: if you do NSLog(@"jsonResponse : %@", jsonResponse);

Comment: i get the same at JSON response

Comment: NSLog(@"array: %@", [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"posts"]);

Comment: that error again - No visible @interface for NSarray declares the selector 'objectForKey'

Comment: it is valid JSON I have used this code in a tableview and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first fragmentize json as

```
NSDictionary * dict = [JSON JSONValue];
```

or

```
NSDictionary * dict = [JSON JSONFragmentValue];
```

then

```
for (NSDictionary* day in dict) {
    shows += [[day objectForKey:@"posts"] count];

    NSLog(@"count : %d",shows);
}
```

Comment: it is the function of JSon library that converts json data into dictionary or array.

Comment: download sbjson and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistakely put "posts" instead of "post". The key "posts" contain an array of dictionary, and each dictionary has a key "post". What you are doing is you take all dictionaries from array in lines

```
  for (NSDictionary* day in jsonResponse) {
```

and check for an key "posts" in dictionary. Really, there is no key called "posts" in dictionary. I is "post". And the value for "post" is a NSDictionary not an array. So you cant call `count` there. The solution for your issue is remove un-necessary APIs inside for loop

```
  [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
  jsonResponse = JSON;

  int shows = 0;
  for (NSDictionary* day in jsonResponse) {
      shows += 1;
  }

  NSLog(@"count : %d",shows);
```